# Full clickable area and vertical alignment of block element inside a table-cell

Tags: html, css

Got a simple question, I need a display block element inside a table-cell to take the full available height and width of the cell while the text is also vertically aligned.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpGPyO)**

```css
ul {
  background: yellow;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 48px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
}

a:hover {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the all thing needs to be responsive so no line-height fix if text drops to 2 lines and number of list elements is flexible that's why I used `display:table`. However happy with another approach if it can achieve this, for some reason I can't figure out how to vertically align the text in this scenario

Comment: if you have fixed height in li tag the you can use` line-heigth:48px` for a tag

Comment: As mentioned that is not a solution if there is longer text and it drops on 2 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end I did in this way and works for my requirements

Demo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpGPyO

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item2 or something longer</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" >Item4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" >Item5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  background: yellow;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 48px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

a:before {
  content:'';
  display: block;
  height: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;      
  z-index: -1;
  width:100%;
}

a:hover:before {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Flexbox** you can archive this:

```css
ul {
  background: yellow;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  align-item:center;
}

li {  
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;    
  /*width:20%;*/
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

a {           
  padding:10px 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

a:hover {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" >Item4 with very very long long long text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" >Item5</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" >Item6</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" >Item7</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the reason I used display table was cause that was giving me the flexibility of having as many list items as I wanted. is there a way I can have that with flexbox? basically don't want the width:20%

Comment: yes, you can remove fixed width from li and more list item... update my answer

Comment: But if you compare my snippet with your one, you will notice how on mine with the display: table the list items are taking the space evenly no matter how much text cause I don't have a problem with the text going on 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

Your Code Complete Right .but **Proper** `vertical-align: middle;` **only remove style** `height: 48px;` **inside** `a` **tag**
**And**
  `li:hover` style replace to `a:hover`

**[Revise Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caaphhdw/3/)**

**update style**

```
a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    word-break: break-all;
 }
```

```css
ul {
  background: yellow;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 48px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;   
  word-break: break-all;
}

li:hover {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item2 Text isveryveryveryvery longer</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work if the text is longer and drops on 2 lines

Comment: you want to text is longer then display 2 line right ??

Comment: i update my answer .check it . in case text is very long then display 2 line and vertically proper display middle. any other query put on comment i solve it

Comment: Unfortunately the clickable area is only taking the full width not the height, it visually looks like is all clickable cause you moved the hover to the list element

Comment: if  clickable area full then add `height:100%` and `padding:12px 0px`